# fireChannelRead() - what is its semantic meaning?

Tags: netty

In Netty, you call `ChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead()` in your handlers when you want to hand over control to the next handler. The docs are written in a bit of an awkward style, making it slightly difficult to get the intended gist at times, which often makes me wonder what a method is supposed to do (even after consulting the Javadoc). For this method, I am specifically wondering what kind of event it is supposed to indicate. The Javadoc says

> A Channel received a message

That really does not make sense from the perspective of the handler using it. Of course the channel has received a message; the handler already knows that since it has received it, so why tell the context? Which makes me think that calling this method has a different meaning, but which:

- "This handler *has read* (past tense) a message from the channel and is finished"
- "The next handler *can read at will* a message from the channel."
- something else?

To me, it would make more sense to notify the context with a method called something like `handlerFinishedRead()` or something. Then the `fireChannelRead()` was reserved for the pipeline to call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with you that the naming of `fireChannelRead()` may not be ideal. I think a good way of thinking about it is that the method fires the `channelRead()` method on the next `ChannelInboundHandler` in the pipeline. It effectively passes the message on to the next ChannelHandler in the pipeline.

Looking at the source for `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`, you'll see that it decides whether to consume the message or not and then either calls `channelRead0` to process it or `fireChannelRead()` to not process it and instead, pass it on to the next handler in the pipeline.
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/deb34a0f8bf719b86aa68f9a242b94db78e9172b/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java#L92-L109

In response to the possible meaning of the method, which you've listed, I would say that it is something else. It isn't necessarily *"This handler has read (past tense) a message from the channel and is finished"* because this handler may not care about the message. It may also have queued work related to the message but not be "finished" with the message, depends on your definition of finished, I suppose. I also wouldn't characterize it as *"The next handler can read at will a message from the channel."* because I don't see this as a synchronization mechanism. the channelRead method is being called on the next handler.

Comment: Great explanation!